# Adding a help text to the question box

Tags: feature-request, question-quality

This might improve the quality of questions from new users.

Both the title and the tag text-box have a help text that describe what you should enter, but not the question box itself.

Could we add a little descriptive text there as well? I think this might catch some low quality questions that only contain a couple of sentences.

I'm not sure what the help-text whould say, but here's an example:

[image]